# Login information remains after server restart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-membership

I have a web application which uses Asp.net Membership for user authenticaton. And as I understand, when user logs in, information about that user is stored in Session, but when I restart the server the user is still logged in.

Shouldnt Session be deleted with server restart? I dont understand how user is still logged in...

Comment: Why do you think it's stored in the session?  Is your code writing anything to the session?  It seems much more likely that the authentication token is in a cookie on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information of a user being logged in is stored in a cookie and it goes between the user's browser and the server with each request.

Restarting the server has nothing to do with the cookie, specifically, the cookie is still valid, it decrypts correctly so the user is considered as logged in.

If you really need to terminate all user sessions, one of ways is changing the application's machine key, the crypto key that is used to encrypt/decrypt auth cookies.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: When users sessions are stored in memory, restarting the server wipes them out. It would therefore be nice to also have the users logged out, so they can start over.

Comment: @SørenMors: not really, imagine you're always logged out of google or facebook just because they restart their servers somewhere. And in-memory sessions are not a good example as often in production environment, database sessions are preferred just to make sure they are not lost in case of accidental server restarts.

Comment: That is true, unfortunately the legacy application that I'm maintaining uses in-memory sessions and does not handle server restarts very well. So the best solution would be to have logins die when the server restarts.

Comment: @SørenMors: manually changing the crypto key sounds like a workaround then.